# Create Buffers that are contained within a polygon with shared attribute

Tags: arcgis-desktop

I'm using ArcGIS Pro to try to solve this problem. I'm mildly competent in ArcPy but have not attempted to script this. What I would like to do is create a buffers that stay contained within the boarders of a parcel polygon with a shared attribute. The buffers are created around a building which is easy enough, I would just like the buffer to not extend outside of the parcel boarder. Not sure if I can make a shapefile in one geoprocess to achieve this goal. I can semi do it with the Intersect tool but the problem with that is the spill over of the buffer is not deleted - just added to the neighboring parcels buffer zone. I'm not sure if I'm clear enough here so I'll incorporate pictures of what i'd like to see.

**If I buffer the buildings you'll see the buffers in red spill over into neighboring parcels naturally**
[image]

**We see that the intersect tool does not remove spill over buffer into the next parcel**

[image]

**This is what I want the butters to look like as one buffer shapefile without manually deleteing all spill over**

[image]

Is this possible with some tool parameter I'm missing?

Comment: Joining your parcels to your buffer using a spatial join then clipping each buffer by it's corresponding parcel ID should do the trick. You can then merge the buffers to create one feature.

Comment: @Tigerwoulds Select tool; Buffer & Parcels. Clip Buffer, loop it and then merge them all at the end. Does that sound about right to what you're describing?

Comment: I would try something like spatial join plot id to your buildings, buffer the output, Union, select by attributes